# What did I do wrong? UPDATE with condition and LIKE postgres

Tags: postgresql

There is a table and I need to update the data in the 3rd column, according to the condition.  If there are brackets, then you need to take information from there, and if not, what is in the first column. Put it where there is no information on the 3rd column. In most cases it is necessary to put where status down or error

https://dbfiddle.uk/GgFft6cY

*here is my request:*

```
    UPDATE table_1
    SET name_3 = 
        CASE
            WHEN name_3 != '' THEN name_3
            WHEN name_1 LIKE '%(%' THEN SUBSTRING(name_1 FROM '%(%' FOR ')')
            ELSE name_1
        END
    WHERE status IN ('down', 'error');
```

*ERROR:  invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced*

what's wrong? or can it be done differently?

Comment: Can you explain what `WHEN name_1 LIKE '%(%' THEN SUBSTRING(name_1 FROM '%(%' FOR ')')` should do?

Comment: checks the value in () if there is, then writes it to column 3 and if not (), then writes everything that is @Jens

Comment: `not equals` in sql is `<>` not `!=`

Comment: After from and for must be a number, not a string

Comment: @Jens: you are right, but `!=` is also accepted by Postgres

Comment: and then how can it be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `FROM` and `FOR` you need a start index and the length, which is a number.

```
 UPDATE table_1
    SET name_3 = 
        CASE
            WHEN name_3 <> '' THEN name_3
            WHEN name_1 LIKE '%(%' THEN SUBSTRING(name_1 FROM POSITION ('(' in name_1)+1 FOR POSITION (')' in name_1) -POSITION ('(' in name_1)-1)
            ELSE name_1
        END
    WHERE status IN ('down', 'error');
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FU7pYBPz)

Comment: only he is together with () and I wanted without them

Comment: @user20881617 have changed my answer

Comment: thank you very much, and if I have another condition after another, how do I write it down? sorry for the additional question, just for the benefit of the horizon.

there is an info_model value, I wanted if there is no () then it takes everything up to _ this character

I understand another ELSE name_1 '%_' ?

Comment: Yes another WHEN ELSE